# How to setup AWS VPC with local (organization's) network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a Jenkins server running on (my organization's) local network. I allocate Jenkins nodes (machines) on this local network as per my need.

Since, the requirements are flexible; we have planned to provision **AWS EC2** machines **as Jenkins slaves**.

This requires setting up the AWS VPC (on which EC2 machines run) and my local network to communicate with each other; i.e. EC2 machines on AWS network and machines on my local network should become part of the same network and able to communicate with each other as if on the same LAN.

What all is required to configure on AWS and on my local network for this setup to work ?

Comment: This page lists the options: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VPN from your local network to connect to private instances in the VPC if that's how you spin the agents up.

If you spin up the agents in a public subnet in the VPC and they get an external IP, you can make sure the security group allows a connection from your local jenkins master and spin them up that way.